# kubectl get secret spews out a gibberish from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

How to fix this base64 decoding? It spews out this gibberish from Jenkins' pod :)

```
printf $(kubectl get secret --namespace default jenkins-16057xxxxx -o jsonpath="{.data.jenkins-admin-password}" | base64 --decode);echo
�K��ly�޷�jg���u�ں"�ϵ�N{߯5��#��
```

Comment: Is the path right? Try it without decoding it to see what you get?

Comment: Yeah, it should be right, because I've got it from: helm status jenkins-16057xxxxx.
Have tried without decoding, but it hasn't helped so far :)

https://pastebin.com/n01mWrRC

Comment: Try krew and the view-secret plugin. Otherwise, remove the -o and the decode and look at the full JSON returned

Comment: 'kubectl get secret' shows up 'jenkins-password' in plain text, however, Jenkins doesn't digest it with the user profile name :)

https://pastebin.com/65bMbuED

Answer (score 1):

Got help from [Bitnami folks](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/4444), turns out base64 decoding is buggy on macOS 11.0.1 - have to fix it then. For the testing purposes, I used that suggested website for decoding a password string successfully.

"Hi @organicnz, I'm not really sure what is happening there. When the chart is deployed, some notes are shown with information about the commands that you need to execute to obtain the credentials. You can obtain those notes again by executing:

helm get notes YOUR_INSTALLATION_NAME

You will find a command like the following one:

echo Password: $(kubectl get secret --namespace default YOUR_INSTALLATION_NAME -o jsonpath="{.data.jenkins-password}" | base64 --decode)

If you want to do what the command above is doing in a more manual way, you can also get the secret and output as yaml and you will get a plain-text string that is base64-encoded. You need to decode it to get the actual password.

If the implementation of your base64 utility is buggy, just for testing purposes, you can use an online tool like this one: https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/base64_decode.html

Again, this is just for testing purposes, you should never share your password on the internet."